# Initialize CSS link decoration

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

I have configured my site's visited link to change color with the following CSS:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none; color: Navy;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: DeepSkyBlue;}
```

It works well.
However, I am unable to initialize the link decoration even when I reload or clear my browser's cache. This is what I want to do:
By reloading by browser, I want the browser to `forget` the links that were visited, i.e, I want the visited link's DeepSkyBlue color changes to the default `Navy` color on page reload.

I am using the latest version of chrome. 
I am OK with using any Chrome extension if necessary. 
A solution with JavaScript or CSS will be fine too.

It seems to have an easy solution, but my research so far has been fruitless.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you @John Thomas for your comments. As you have anticipated, I have had a:active set to color "Navy". As per you suggestion, I have tried a hard reset of the cache, unfortunately without any improvement!

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS and Chrome issue. Yes, you cleared your cache, but the cache in Chrome is like bubble gum on the bottom of your shoe. I think with developer tools open it is Shift + refresh choose hard refresh no cache.

With CSS it used to be that you had to list all 4 for them to work properly. That is probably not your problem though, might be worth ruling out. It is possible it is picking up the active state if the active state has not be set.

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
a:link { color: Navy; } 
a:visited { color: DeepSkyBlue; }
a:hover { color: Navy; } 
a:active { color: Navy ;}
```

Comment: I love your simile "bubble gum on the bottom of your shoe"! Thanks for the laugh.